# How to make an alias for a column in SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, json

Saying that I have such a SQL table named `hotel` as below:

```
id   numOfRoom
1       30
2       20
3       40
```

I'm building a web server with Python so I use some interface to fetch my database.

```
query = 'select * from hotel where id = 1'
// connect db
result = cursor.fetchone()
```

Now the type of `result` is Dictionary so I can do like this:

```
print(result['id'])  # 1
print(result['numOfRoom'])   #30
```

In my project, I need to generate a JSON and send it to frontend:

```
{
    "id":result['id'],
    "numOfRoom":result['numOfRoom']
}
```

However, in this case, the frontend can't get the right keys, because `numOfRoom` is not the right thing for users. For users, they need to get things like `number of rooms`.

So, I regenerate a JSON:

```
{
    "id":result['id'],
    "number of rooms":result['numOfRoom']
}
```

Now the frontend can simply show `key:value` and users are happy.

But I think this is not a good idea. Because if I update my sql table, I have a touch my backend code. Is it possible to make aliases for the columns in SQL and I get them immediately so that I can code to generate JSON as below:

```
myjson = generateEmptyJson()
foreach val in result:
    myjson.append("val.getAlias()":"val.getValue()")
```

Comment: What you will have is seperation of data and representation. It's a good thing. Just exposing the content of the database to the user is worst practice. Also JSON is still not a format to be shown to the user. There are many places where you have to give a proper label to the data outside the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative possibility might be to create a VIEW in your database.

Underlying changed table:

```
create changed_hotel (id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, total_rooms int);
```

view to reflect what your app is looking for:

```
create view  my_view as
select id, total_rooms as numOfRoom from changed_hotel;
```

You'd have to check the syntax in SQL Server (not one I'm familiar with) and make sure it can do DML on views- Not all DB's can.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the value in the SQL statement:

```
select h.id, h.numOfRoom as [Number of Rooms]
from hotel
where id = 1;
```

You'll still need to change the SQL if you change the underlying structure.